# Move Bootstrap carousel indicators outside and change their icons

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to move Bootstrap carousel indicator outside of the carousel div and change their icons with font awesome icons.

Please check below image as a example.
[image]

This is design requirement, I couldn't figure how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Please share your code which have you tried..

Comment: Sorry didn't work, I also want to change indicator icons.

Comment: check now , hope it works @Mudassar

Comment: @Ahmad Thanks, I found a JQuery to move them on desire place but still couldn't find a way to change their icon. Can you help regarding icons.

Comment: yeah sure @Mudassar, check my answer i provided some links to change their icons

Comment: i added a new link now too , check it @Mudassar

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad its worked perfectly. :)

Comment: you're **welcome** @Mudassar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push them to the right of the slider like this...

```
    .carousel-indicators {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    right: 2% !important;
    left: inherit;
}
```

or this:

```
.carousel-indicators {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
right: 0;
z-index: 15;
width: 60%;
margin-right: 20px;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
}
```

and check [Styling bootstrap carousel indicators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937072/styling-bootstrap-carousel-indicators)
 or [Bootstrap Carousel Indicator with Numbers](https://codepen.io/danbhala/pen/gpWvxG) or [Bootstrap carousel with font awesome icon](https://gist.github.com/TANVIRFAZLEY/f40cc3723a3db4edc13ed3c2cfadc8b3)  for **different styles** of carousel indicators.

**Hope this is helpful :)**